# Strange MVC3 performance issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, performance, mvc-mini-profiler

I have a strange issue that is occurring before my code appears to reach my controller.

From using the SO Mini-MVC-Profiler, I've found that a certain request is taking 500ms (500ms!!!), and for what I know it is doing; it's excessively high!

[image]

We do use unity IoC to create our dependencies, and in the ase of the below EntityController being created, there is a AppServices dependently to be created, which does require some service classes to be instantiated, but I wouldn't expect this takes 500ms, it's simply constructors.

Is there any way I could debug to find out specifically where time is being taken up?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this issue was either resolved with '' or it was a non-issue

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is not the answer you're looking for and is not fancy either but you can use [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

Comment: Could suggest where this could be used?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try profile your code, for example use Ant profiler. 
It tell you where is time gap occurs.